# Displaying an image, Java

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm new to Java GUI, and am having issues displaying an image. My intention is to display a large image and allow the user to click on regions of the image to indicate where certain features are located. Anyway, I'm getting a rough start because I can't even get the image to appear, despite reading Oracle's explanation and other solutions.

I've created a JFrame and used its setContentPane() method to add a JPanel and JLabel. I use the setIcon() method of the JLabel to add an image to it, or at least that's my intention...

Any advice is appreciated, especially if there's a better way of doing this. I'll be using OpenCV to process images, and plan to convert them to Java image (or BufferedImage) before displaying them.

Here is the code. I left out the libraries to save space.

```
public class Pathology {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimaryFrame primaryFrame = new PrimaryFrame(); 
        primaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        primaryFrame.setSize(1500, 900);
        primaryFrame.setVisible( true );        
        primaryFrame.setContentPane(primaryFrame.getGui()); 

        try {
            primaryFrame.setImage(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\Pictures\\Pathology\\C\\001.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

GUI Class:

```
public class PrimaryFrame extends JFrame{
    //private JTextField textField1;
    JPanel gui; 
    JLabel imageCanvas; 

    public PrimaryFrame() {
        super( "Pathology-1" );
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //textField1 = new JTextField("Chup!", 50); 
        //add(textField1);

    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        imageCanvas.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }
    public void initComponents() {
        if (gui==null) { 
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
            imageCanvas = new JLabel();

            JPanel imageCenter = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageCenter.add(imageCanvas);
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageCenter);
            imageScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            gui.add(imageScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    public Container getGui() {
        initComponents();
        return gui;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you laugh at me if I'd tell you that you just have to put the `primaryFrame.setVisible( true );` to the end of the main method? :)

For furture understanding, you don't have to call `frame.setVisible(true)` every time you want to add/update something in the frame (in an ActionListener, for example). Instead you can call `frame.revalidate()` and `frame.repaint()`. (Where frame can be replaced with the particular panel)

Comment: Thanks, LuxxMiner. I'm still working to grasp these basic fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `setVisible(true)` *after* the call to `setImage()`:

```
primaryFrame.setImage(ImageIO.read(new
    File("C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\Pictures\\Pathology\\C\\001.png")));
```

because any update to the GUI after `setVisible()` will not be shown.

That's it and the code should be like this:

```
public class Pathology {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimaryFrame primaryFrame = new PrimaryFrame(); 
        primaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        primaryFrame.setSize(1500, 900);
        primaryFrame.setContentPane(primaryFrame.getGui()); 

        try {
            primaryFrame.setImage(ImageIO.read(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\Pictures\\Pathology\\C\\001.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primaryFrame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```